# List.Add function adds reference to the object or adds its value in the list

Tags: c#

I have a program to print all possible combinations from a string array. The printing is done fine on the screen. However, When I add the same to a list, all list members reflect the last generated combination. So, I am not sure what is happening. Please see the code below.

```
class Program
{
    static List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>(); 
    static void combinationUtil(string[] arr, string[] data,
                                int start, int end,
                                int index, int r)
    {
        // Current combination is  
        // ready to be printed,  
        // print it 
        if (index == r)
        {
            list.Add(data);
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(data[j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return;
        }

        // replace index with all 
        // possible elements. The  
        // condition "end-i+1 >=  
        // r-index" makes sure that  
        // including one element 
        // at index will make a  
        // combination with remaining  
        // elements at remaining positions 
        for (int i = start; i <= end &&
                  end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++)
        {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1,
                            end, index + 1, r);
        }
    }

    // The main function that prints 
    // all combinations of size r 
    // in arr[] of size n. This  
    // function mainly uses combinationUtil() 
    static void printCombination(string[] arr,
                                 int n, int r)
    {
        // A temporary array to store  
        // all combination one by one 
        string[] data = new string[r];

        // Print all combination  
        // using temprary array 'data[]' 
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0,
                        n - 1, 0, r);
    }

    // Driver Code 
    static public void Main()
    {
        string[] arr = { "string-1", "string-2", "string-3", "string-4" };
        int r = 2;
        int n = arr.Length;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item[0]+" "+item[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the output

[image]

Comment: When you perform `list.Add(data)` you are adding a reference to `data` to the list. It's not a copy of `data`. You need something like `string[] data = new string[r];` to create a new instance for every item in the list.

Comment: @BoilermakerRV In this case, you are totally right because `string[]` is a reference type. In general however it depends on whether data is a *reference type* or a *value type* (like e.g. `int`).

Comment: @BoilermakerRV I sort of got the idea. But unable to find the right way to do this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. But, I am not sure if this is the only and best way to do this. If you have any other way of doing this better, please answer. Following is how I did this.

```
list.Add(new string[2] { data[0], data[1] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `List`. Note the `string[] uniquePair = new string[2];` prior to each `list.Add()`.

```
class Program
{
    static List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

    // Driver Code 
    static public void Main()
    {
        string[] arr = { "string-1", "string-2", "string-3", "string-4" };
        int r = 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                string[] uniquePair = new string[2];
                uniquePair[0] = arr[i];
                uniquePair[1] = arr[j];
                list.Add(uniquePair);
            }
        }

        foreach (string[] pair in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ pair[0] } + { pair[1] }");
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string-1 + string-2
string-1 + string-3
string-1 + string-4
string-2 + string-3
string-2 + string-4
string-3 + string-4
```